# file .ics to delete appointment not recognized by outlook

Tags: icalendar

I send a icalendar when a user create an appointment on my application and the file ics is regularly recognized by outlook.
If the user delete the appointment on my application i send a icalendar with canceled notation, but the .ics file is not recognized (not supported calendar message.ics)

Icalendar which create the appointment on outlook (regular recognized):

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR 
PRODID:-//Schedule a Meeting
VERSION:2.0
METHOD:CANCEL
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART:20190718T033000Z
DTSTAMP:20190718T113347Z
DTEND:20190718T040000Z
LOCATION: 
UID:Tesis10910
DESCRIPTION:
X-ALT-DESC;FMTTYPE=text/html:
SUMMARY:
STATUS:CANCELLED
ORGANIZER:MAILTO:fc@newteamsoftware.com
ATTENDEE;CN="fc@newteamsoftware.com";ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;RSVP=TRUE:mailto:fc@newteamsoftware.com
BEGIN:VALARM
TRIGGER:-PT15M
ACTION:DISPLAY
DESCRIPTION:Reminder
END:VALARM
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Icalendar which delete the appointment:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//Schedule a Meeting
VERSION:2.0
METHOD:CANCEL
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART:20190718T033000Z
DTSTAMP:20190718T113347Z
DTEND:20190718T040000Z
LOCATION: 
UID:Tesis10911
DESCRIPTION:
X-ALT-DESC;FMTTYPE=text/html:
SUMMARY:
STATUS:CANCELLED
ORGANIZER:MAILTO:fc@newteamsoftware.com
ATTENDEE;CN="fc@newteamsoftware.com";ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;RSVP=TRUE:mailto:fc@newteamsoftware.com
BEGIN:VALARM
TRIGGER:-PT15M
ACTION:DISPLAY
DESCRIPTION:Reminder
END:VALARM
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Answer (score 1):

Few things:

- don't know if it is intended but your first iMIP message already has a METHOD:CANCEL instead of REQUEST.
- your second iMIP message has a different UID. If this is really what you are sending, it is normal for the client not to recognise it as the cancel of the first message.
- Your second message lacks a SEQUENCE property with an increased value. See https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5546#section-3.2.5
- there is no point in adding the VALARM component. Clients will always ignore it.